# How can I add a border to the Drop-down area of a ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, listbox

I am using the following code to override and draw each list item within a ListBox.

```
      if (e.Index < 0) return;
        // if the item state is selected then change the back color 
        if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
            e = new DrawItemEventArgs(e.Graphics,
                                      e.Font,
                                      e.Bounds,
                                      e.Index,
                                      e.State ^ DrawItemState.Selected,
                                      e.ForeColor,
                                      Color.Red); // Choose the color

        // Draw the background of the ListBox control for each item.
        e.DrawBackground();
        // Draw the current item text
        e.Graphics.DrawString(studentsListBox.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        // If the ListBox has focus, draw a focus rectangle around the selected item.
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
```

The code is works as I would suspect, however I would also like to add a border to the entire drop-down portion of the list box (see the example image below.)  How can I add the border to the entire list?

[image]

Comment: You're asking two questions-- How can you draw a border on the drop-down list and how can you modify the look of each element in your list?  Please update your question to reflect the nature of your question or ask two separate SO questions.  Thank you.

Comment: @RLH i modified my question would you pls help on this one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the title is referring to the border, I'll focus on that.  I'm assuming you want to change the BorderStyle beyond just the given "None", "FixedSingle" and "Fixed3D"?

The ListBox does not support any kind of BorderColors, etc.

Your best bet is to change change the `BorderStyle to "None"`, `IntegralHeight = False`, and `Dock = Fill`, and then place it inside a panel.

For your panel, change `BorderStlye = None`, `Padding (All) = 2`, `BackColor = Red`.

With WinForms, your choices are limited.

Comment: one more question i want to add the data like indicated in figure and title also ....how will i do that would you pls give any idea ....

Comment: @user899271 You are already using DrawString, try changing the font to bold for the header items and change your e.Bounds rectangle to indent it to the right for your subitems.  Instead of a listbox, this looks like a TreeView, maybe try using that control instead.